# Cant call _head attribute on my python class I created

Tags: python, class, init

I have 2 classes, one class called storage and one class called library. The storage class has a list made up of nodes.

The Library class needs to be able to have a storage object inside it to hold its data.

I want to have it so when I call any of the storage methods, they work inside the library class as well.

I have a method that gets the head node of the list, and it works fine when I do the following:

```
objstor = Storage()
# I add some nodes to the list
print(objstor._head) and this works and gives me the first nodes head
```

When I create a library class that use the storage class to store its data this happens:

```
objlib = Library()
# i add data to the storage class within the library class
print(objlib._head) gives me an error ''Library' object has no attribute '_head'
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: It's very hard to show you how to fix your code if you don't show us your code. Please read [mcve] in the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the `Library` class has a member that's a `Storage` doesn't mean it has all the attributes of `Storage`.

Think about it this way:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 2
```

Now `Spam` uses the `int` class to store its data. Do you expect it to work like an `int`?

There's no difference here. Just because `Library` uses a `Storage` to store its data doesn't mean it *is* a `Storage`.

---

If you actually want `Library` to be a `Storage` rather than just use one, you do that with inheritance:

```
class Library(Storage):
    def __init__(self, some, args):
        super().__init__(whatever, args, Storage, needs)
```

---

But usually, you don't want that. You just want to access the `Storage`, and then access its members:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, some, args):
        self.storage = Storage(whatever, args, Storage, needs)

lib = Library(whatever)
print(lib.storage._head)
```

Comment: Ah, so to access the head of library I would always have to do library.storage._head and cant do library._head directly? I see.